# overflow menu function onCreateOptionsMenu never called

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am trying too implement a overflow menu on a simple application, however the overflow menu does not render on the application. I tried to call a Log.d on the function onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) too see if the function is even called and as I excepted it is not called! I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

here is the relevent code for the overflow menu.

in the settings class is where I call the function onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

```
public class SettingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);
        Log.d("ERROR","SOMETHING");
//        creating recycler view
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        items.add(new Item("counter name 1","enter name here"));
        items.add(new Item("counter name 2","enter name here"));
        items.add(new Item("counter name 3", "enter name here"));
        items.add(new Item("Max counts","enter max count here"));
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(),items));


    }

    //    creating the overflow menu
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Log.d("ERROR","SOMETHING");
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.overflow_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    //    creating a callback method to know what option was selected in the overflow menu

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

//        once the edit settings is pressed the user will be able to edit the page
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.edit_settings){
            Toast.makeText(this,"item selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

in the activity_settings xml file I made a toolbar and a recycler view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".SettingActivity">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-16dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/settings_activity_bar"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@null"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/back_arrow_icon" />




    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="109dp"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/save"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recycler_view" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and finally i have the overflow_menu xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".activity.SettingActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/edit_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="@string/edit_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never"
         />

</menu>
```

Please help!!